# How to read and change the header text of template column in telerik rad grid on edit popup

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

How to read and change the header text of template column in telerik radgrid on edit popup

Comment: have you tried any thing...if yes share what issue u are facing and if no then go and give it a try and come back

Comment: I tried to access it in ItemDatabound method but here I can find controls by id, but how to change Template column Header Text.....

Answer (score 1):

you can do that in two ways

first

```
var TableView = RadGrid1.MasterTableView;
var column = TableView.GetColumn("id");
column.HeaderText = "newid";
TableView.Rebind();
```

second

```
For example you can modify the header item on Page_PreRender:
protected void Page_PreRender(object o, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  GridHeaderItem headerItem = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Header)[0] as GridHeaderItem; 
  headerItem["myTemplateColumn"].Text = "MODIFIED"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This way we can change the header text of grid but when Edit popUp opens it shows the previous values. This is my real problem.